# How to record video in android using camera API like Vine, Instagram, Twitter?

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture

I will try to record using camera api in android. I will done it using mediaRecorder.
But I want to record square (aspect ratio 1:1 )videos like instagram/vine/twitter?
I was try but I'm not getting right solution for it.
Is there any way to record square video?
How to record video using opencv/javacv/FFmpeg?

Comment: There is no requirement for a camera to support a square resolution. You may need to take a regular video, then crop it (e.g., on your server).

Comment: Instagram does on client side so how they can do?

Comment: Either they record a video and crop it, or they assemble a video from square-cropped camera preview images. Vine took that latter approach, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), you can use `setVideoSize` to set the size of your video.